# O que são e como funcionam os Core Web Vitals, devo me preocupar com eles?

Tags: desempenho, navegador-de-internet, seo, ux, web-vitals

Vi recentemente que o Google vai considerar os relatórios de **Web Vitals** (Lighthouse e Search
Console) como fator de *rankeamento*, pois esses fatores podem interferir diretamente na experiencia do usuário com a página. Mas isso é uma coisa exclusiva do Google ou seria uma boa prática geral, por exemplo, mesmo para um **SaaS** eu devo levar isso em consideração?

Em resumo, o que exatamente são essas métricas de avaliação do **Core Web Vitals**? Ficou um pouco confuso para mim. Me parece uma imposição do Google, mas é preciso se preocupar com isso em sistemas web que nada tem a ver com o Google?

Comment: Link do comunicado oficial do Google https://webmasters.googleblog.com/2020/05/evaluating-page-experience.html

Answer (score 2):

vi que a pergunta foi feita há um bom tempo e espero que a resposta ainda seja útil. Coincidentemente tive de pesquisar melhor sobre e acabei percebendo que as métricas além de influenciarem o rankeamento, obviamente afeta a performance de sua aplicação, que fatalmente irá afetar a experiência das pessoas que usam e consequentemente o índice de satisfação do usuário.

Ou seja, tem a parte técnica, mas tem muita experiência de usuário envolvida aqui sim. O meu campo de pesquisa atual é a acessibilidade e neste caso, estou focado com a acessibilidade simples e eficiente da informação apresentada. Se eu tenho um problema pra exibir essa mensagem (que pode estar relacionado com a demora que ela é exibida ao usuário) eu afeto a experiência e consequentemente a acessibilidade da informação também.

A página oficial explicando detalhadamente cada uma das métricas e demonstrando quais ferramentas você são utilizadas para que você obtenha os relatórios de que precisa é essa: https://web.dev/vitals/

**Resumindo as métricas:**

[LCP (Largest Contentful Paint)](https://web.dev/lcp/): mede o tempo de carregamento das informações, se demorar mais do que 2,5 segundos tá ruim...

[FID (First Input Delay)](https://web.dev/fid/): mede o tempo de interação a partir do momento que o usuário clica em um botão até a execução da função que o botão faz, por exemplo.

[CLS (Cumulative Layout Shift)](https://web.dev/cls/): mede a consistência do layout... as vezes os elementos da tela mudam de lugar, devido a uma ação anterior. Por exemplo, você clicou em algo e apareceu algo na tela que não existia antes e isso fez com que os elementos anteriores se deslocasse, o que pode ocasionar uma confusão no usuário.

Principalmente esse último (CLS) você tem regras inclusive na WCAG relacionadas a boas práticas de acessibilidade e você pode pesquisar o critério [3.2.3 - Navegação Consistente](https://www.w3.org/WAI/WCAG21/Understanding/consistent-navigation), mas todos impactam na experiência como um todo.

**Resumindo as ferramentas:**

[Relatório de Experiência de Usuário do Chrome](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-user-experience-report) que pode te ajudar principalmente com estatísticas sobre o tempo de carregamento das informações na tela.

[Page Speed Insights](https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/insights/) que é a ferramenta que irá te mostrar como você está de fato e o que precisa fazer pra melhorar em cada ponto das métricas do Vitals. (se você instalar o plugin LIGHTHOUSE no Chrome, você obtém os mesmos resultados)

[Google Search Console](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/9205520) que vai unificar as informações em dashboards bonitos e fáceis de configurar.

Enfim, espero que a resposta ainda tenha sido útil.

abs
Marcelo Sales

Comment: Valeu a resposta Marcelo, do ponto de vista da acessibilidade faz muita diferença mesmo e não pode ser deixado de lado, até pq quem não cuidar de deixar tudo acessível pode acabar processado rss, pena ver que algumas empresas só se mexem quando sentem no bolso....